# Comparison of Processing vs JavaFx vs Griffon

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics, comparison, toolkit

Can anybody compare Processing vs plain JavaFX vs Griffon with Swing/Fx builders? I am interested in the sweet spots of each tooklkit, and in particular for building rich visualization dashboards.

Comment: This is not a Stackoverflow question. I've asked that this be moved to [programmers.stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 5):

You're asking for a comparison between a language/environment (Processing), a set of java libraries (JavaFX) and an application framework (Griffon). As you can see, it wouldn't be fair for one tech to be compared to the other two.

However, I must mention that Griffon supports both Processing and JavaFX via plugins, which means that any cool stuff you build with those two can be embedded in a Griffon application ;-)

Comment: My question was really which one is more suitable for rich non-interactive data visualizations. Originally I was leaning towards processing, but as I see it, it is a weird extra API on top of Java2D that I have to learn and I am not sure whether it is worth it. Then we have JavaFX, driven by Visage, Java or Groovy (choices, choices...) and finally, the question whether it is useful to use Griffon to bind them given it is not the typical form-based 'show me your beans' application.